# system cannot find the file specified in a module downloader python program

Tags: python, pip, installation

i am writing small module downloader program
it should just pip install a given wheel file of a module
(that i putted in the same folder)
but when i run it it says:
'WindowsError [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified'

here is my code:

```
import subprocess as sub

def install_module(module):
    out = sub.check_output(['pip','install',module])
    if out.split(' ')[2] == 'satisfied:':
        print 'already installed!',module + ' is already installed!'
    else:
        print '',module + ' installed succesfully!'

install_module('Pygame')
```

thanks for any help
and sorry for my English

Comment: do you have `pip` installed globally? becuase `sub.checkout` isn't finding it.

Comment: yes i do have pip installed globally - i can download modules by hand

Comment: just wondering, does `out = sub.check_output(['pip','install',module], shell=True)` still produce the error?

Comment: it now makes a new error - CalledProcessError: Command '['pip', 'install', 'Pygame']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Comment: That's good:) that means it ran `pip` and `pip` exited with a non-zero status, aka something failed.

Comment: i found the problem thanks for the help! :)